# how install MySQL Workbench v8.0.33 on windows 10 32-bit PC?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I can install the MS installer, but when I try to add a custom install of MySQL Workbench, it does not appear in the list of applications. Also, whilst I do not want a MySQL Server, the only versions that appear are 5.6 & 5.7, not v8.x.

I have reviewed other related questions and answers but nothing appears relevant. For example, I appear to have all the pre-requisites like .NET Framework and Visual.

I have rebooted the PC several times, removed and re-installed the MSInstaller, both the web-community and community versions but nothing ever even gives the option of MySQL Workbench, any version of it. I have tried to update the packages on offer, and tried various options like GA, other releases, all software, applications etc, but nothing ever results in Workbench being available to be intalled.

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG AND WHAT CAN I DO TO PUT IT RIGHT?

PS: I used to have a working copy of Workbench (v6 I think) but I uninstalled it to get ready for the new version, so my system was at least compatible with that version.